# How to calculate time difference of rows using Lag/Lead in DB2?

Tags: sql, syntax, db2, lag

I have this following table:

```
id Date       Hour  Description   Username
1  2015-05-13 10:08 SessionClosed Thierry
2  2015-05-12 23:30 SessionClosed Leao
3  2015-05-12 20:50 SessionOpened Thierry
4  2015-05-11 17:10 SessionOpened Leao
```

How can I calculate the difference in time of each user's session?

I'm using DB2.

The result should look like this:

```
id Date       Hour  Description   Username DiffTime
1  2015-05-13 10:08 SessionClosed Thierry  14:18
2  2015-05-12 23:30 SessionClosed Leao     30:20
3  2015-05-12 20:50 SessionOpened Thierry  00:00
4  2015-05-11 17:10 SessionOpened Leao     00:00
```

Comment: And the result should look like?

Comment: I just edited the question and put what the result would be.

Comment: Is it possible for a user to have more than one session open at a time?  What is the purpose of having the "DiffTime" of "00:00" for the session opened rows?

Comment: It isn't possible. Actually, I just need this DiffTime for SessionClosed rows. This time operation can be ignored for SessionOpened rows.